# Xpath of investing.com for scraping

Tags: web-scraping, xpath, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to import data from https://www.investing.com/equities/boc-hong-kong-historical-data by `importxml` formula in Google Sheets. It can be done by `importhtml` but i would like to import it by xpath becase it would not has scraping updates issues.
I used `IMPORTXML("https://www.investing.com/equities/boc-hong-kong-historical-data","//*[@id='curr_table']")` and then it **scraped** but in bad shape; for example it does not specify rows and columns or Comma-delimited.

How can I extract data by xPath in Google Sheets?

Comment: Please describe in the body of the question the relevant parts of the source code of the referred page. Also add a brief description of your search/research efforts regarding how to use xPath with IMPORTXML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the table in the URL of `=IMPORTHTML("https://www.investing.com/equities/boc-hong-kong-historical-data","table",2)` using the xpath on Google Spreadsheet.

#### Modified formula:

In order to retrieve the values using the xpath, please use the following xpath.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.investing.com/equities/boc-hong-kong-historical-data","//table[@id='curr_table']//tr")
```

- In this case, the xpath is `//table[@id='curr_table']//tr`.
- Also, you can use the xpath of `//*[@id='curr_table']//tr`.

#### Result:

[image]

#### Note:

- As another method, I think that `IMPORTHTML` can be also used like below. This is the same with above formula.

  ```
    =IMPORTHTML("https://www.investing.com/equities/boc-hong-kong-historical-data","table",2)
  ```

#### References:

- [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342)
- [IMPORTHTML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093339)